# How to stretch QBoxLayout in PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, stretch, boxlayout

how to stretch the QHboxLayout and QVBoxLayout in PyQT5? Which method should I use? The pictures of result are given in links (as you see when window is small it also doesn't fit in the shape of the window)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, 
QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QDesktopWidget
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        label1 = QLabel('Введите слова')
        words = QTextEdit()

        label2 = QLabel('Результат')
        result = QTextEdit()

        vbox1 = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox1.addStretch(1)
        vbox1.addWidget(label1)
        vbox1.addWidget(words)

        vbox2 = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox2.addStretch(1)
        vbox2.addWidget(label2)
        vbox2.addWidget(result)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addLayout(vbox1)
        hbox.addLayout(vbox2)
        self.setLayout(hbox)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('try')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Small window

[image]

Full window

[image]

Comment: Remove the three `addStretch` lines and it will work.

Comment: apparently I don't understand the meaning of addStretch

Comment: That is what the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#details) is for. The `addStetch` method adds a stretchable spacer item to the layout. So it will push the widgets over and create an area of blank space. Normally, widgets mostly just expand to fill the available space (depending on their size-policy, amongst other things). See the [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) overview for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put hbox to QWidget and set it as central widget.

```
main_widget = QWidget()
main_widget.setLayout(hbox)
self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
```